# Second-Order Ordinary Differential Equation System

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, systems-of-equations

If we have second-order ordinary differential equation system
$$\begin{cases}
F''(x)=(F(x))^3+F(x)(G(x))^2\\
G''(x)=2G(x)(F(x))^2
\end{cases}$$
and it satisfies boundary conditions
$$F(0)=G'(0)=1,\qquad F'(0)=G(0)=0.$$
Find $F\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$.

It seems that $F=G$, we have
$$
F''=2F^3\Rightarrow F'F''=2F'F^3\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\left( F' \right) ^2=\frac{1}{2}F^4+\frac{1}{2}C_1,
$$
that is $F'=\pm \sqrt{F^4+C_1}$, So
$$
\int_0^x{\frac{1}{\sqrt{F^4+C_1}}dt}=\pm x+C_2.
$$
But I think it may have some problems with the boundary conditions.

**Edit:** In fact, $F(x)=1/\cos x,G(x)=\tan x$, but how can we prove it?

Comment: Why do you think that $F=G$? It seems that they can't be equal because $F(0)=1$ and $G(0)=0$.

Comment: @Tomi27 Yes, you are right!

Comment: What exactly is the context of this question? Is it to try out some exotic symbolic solution method or is it to explore the possibilities and limits of numerical integrators?

Comment: You can get
$$
F'(x)^2+\frac12G'(x)^2-\frac12F(x)^4-F(x)^2G(x)^2
$$
as a constant of the dynamics. Numerical integration shows that the result is more or less exactly $2$.

Comment: @LutzL I'm trying to solve this equation, and it is also ok if you have numerical method.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `python` `scipy` integrators with the script

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
def odefunc(y,t):
    F,dF,G,dG = y;
    return [ dF, F**3+F*G**2, dG, 2*G*F**2 ]
y0 = [1., 0., 0., 1.]
sol = odeint(odefunc, y0, [0,np.pi/3],atol=1e-14, rtol=1e-13,mxstep=10000)
print "%.14f"%sol[-1,0]
```

gives the value $F(\pi/3)$ as

```
2.00000000000097
```

Other software with numerical integrators should work in a similar way.

---

Or modify to

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,11)*np.pi/3
sol = odeint(ode, y0, x,atol=1e-14, rtol=1e-13,mxstep=10000)
def E(y): 
    F,dF,G,dG = y; 
    return dF**2 + 0.5*dG**2 - 0.5*F**4 - (F*G)**2
for xx,y in zip(x,sol): 
    print "x=%.2f*pi/3, F(x)=%.14f, E(x)=%.14f"%(xx*3/np.pi, y[0], E(y))
```

to get the result

```
x=0.00*pi/3, F(x)=1.00000000000000, E(x)=0.00000000000000
x=0.10*pi/3, F(x)=1.00550827956352, E(x)=0.00000000000001
x=0.20*pi/3, F(x)=1.02234059486504, E(x)=0.00000000000002
x=0.30*pi/3, F(x)=1.05146222423829, E(x)=0.00000000000003
x=0.40*pi/3, F(x)=1.09463627850608, E(x)=0.00000000000005
x=0.50*pi/3, F(x)=1.15470053837930, E(x)=0.00000000000013
x=0.60*pi/3, F(x)=1.23606797749988, E(x)=0.00000000000047
x=0.70*pi/3, F(x)=1.34563272960657, E(x)=0.00000000000225
x=0.80*pi/3, F(x)=1.49447654986494, E(x)=0.00000000000307
x=0.90*pi/3, F(x)=1.70130161670461, E(x)=0.00000000000392
x=1.00*pi/3, F(x)=2.00000000000092, E(x)=0.00000000001329
```

where the energy function as theoretically conserved quantity indicates the error level of the numerical result.